# Dump git history as a single file?

Tags: git

I'd like to share repository as single file.

How can I export history into single file and import it on other side?

Is it possible to limit history with usual git syntax, like `v1..v2`?

Comment: Even though that's not a single file, can't you just clone your repository as a bare repository?

Comment: Are you wanting a grip of a repo?

Comment: Sorry... *gzip not grip

Comment: In Git, *blob* is a technical term referring to stored file data within a repository. So it is probably best to avoid that word in your description of what you want. Anyway, `git bundle` is indeed the way to do this in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to create a git bundle.
This will create a package that can be cloned later.

You can do this with the [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) command.

Example (taken from [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Bundling)):

```
$ git bundle create repo.bundle HEAD master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 441 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)


$ git clone repo.bundle repo
Cloning into 'repo'...
...
$ cd repo
$ git log --oneline
9a466c5 second commit
b1ec324 first commit
```